# Missing hard disk space

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, disk-space

I'm trying to figure out where my missing hard disk space is going.  I'm using `du` and `df` from the command line and there seems to be a clear discrepancy.

So here's the `du` output:

```
$ sudo du -h -d 1 /
 59M    /.DocumentRevisions-V100
1.9M    /.fseventsd
  0B    /.PKInstallSandboxManager
1.6G    /.Spotlight-V100
  0B    /.Trashes
  0B    /.vol
 20G    /Applications
2.6M    /bin
  0B    /cores
5.0K    /dev
1.0K    /home
4.6G    /Library
1.0K    /net
  0B    /Network
 78M    /opt
7.2G    /private
1020K   /sbin
 11G    /System
264G    /Users
1.7G    /usr
4.0K    /Volumes
310G    /
```

Now here's the `df` output:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     465Gi  417Gi   48Gi    90% 109334564 12511744   90%   /
devfs          213Ki  213Ki    0Bi   100%       737        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0        0  100%   /home
```

`df` is showing me 417gb used and `du` is showing 310gb used.  How do I find the 100 missing gigabytes?

I'm running OS X 10.9.5 on a 2013 512gb MacBook Air.

Comment: If the system hasn't been rebooted for a while, I would do this first and run du/df again.

Comment: 3 thoughts: Have you tried disk utility > verify and repair disk? Have you tried a GUI analyzer like disk inventory x (http://www.derlien.com/)? Have you tried including the -r flag ("Generate messages about directories that cannot be read"). See 'man du'

Comment: the `-r` flag is the default according to my `man du`.  I've rebooted just a few hours ago.  I'll run the disk verification.