# Macbook air 100 GB hidden space + error when verifying volume

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I used DailyDisk to analyse my Macbook Air (Late 2014, 256GB SSD).
Result: 100GB of hidden space => No idea where this is coming from

What I tried:
- tmutil listlocalsnapshots / => I have no local snapshots
- diskutil verifyVolume / => error: invalid value 18604, 20 (see screenshot)

Do you have any idea on how to repair my disk and get my disk space back?

[image]

Comment: did you run `fsck_apfs`

Comment: It is run automatically when I run the command diskutil verifyVolume /

Answer (score 1):

Forget the space calculations if your disk has accounting errors.

1. Back up any data that’s not already safe.
2. Try repairs until you’re out of patience or feel it’s not going to work
3. Erase the drive (Apple support erase install guide is below - search for erase or format)
4. Re-run the disk check.
5. If you have a clean check, then validate the storage settings before you load any data. Erase again if you aren’t convinced the clean install is correct.
6. Seek hardware service or repair if the check won’t pass after two erases.

   - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have the exact same problem and haven't been able to find any solution :(

From the hours of research I've done, this post here seems to work for some other with this issue; [OS X 10.11.6 Missing over 200GB of disk space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261829/os-x-10-11-6-missing-over-200gb-of-disk-space?rq=1)

Perhaps it'll help/work for you?